# Need to transpose a LARGE csv file in perl

Tags: perl, csv, large-files, transpose

The csv data file is 3.2 GB in total, with god knows how many rows and columns (assume very large). The file is a genomics data with SNP data for a population of individuals. Thus the csv file contains IDs such as `TD102230` and genetic data such as `A/A` and `A/T`.

Now that I used `Text::CSV` and `Array::Transpose` modules but couldn't seem to get it right (as in the computing cluster froze). Is there specific module that would do this? I am new to Perl (not much experience in low level programming, mostly used R and MATLAB before) so detailed explanations especially welcome!

Comment: Tried to load the file at once and the computer punished me quite harshly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As direct answer, you should read file line by line, process them with `Text::CSV`, push new values to arrays with each array corresponds to original column and then just output them with `join` or like to get transposed representation of original. Disposing of each array right after `join` will help with memory problem too.

Writing values to external files instead of array and joining them with OS facilities is another way around memory requirements.

You also should think about why you need this. Is there really no better way to solve real task at hand, since transposing just by itself serves no real purpose?

Comment: I am using another program which takes the data in one format but the raw data I have is the transpose, that's why I am trying to flip the data.

Answer (score 0):

Break down the task into several steps to save memory.

1. Read a line and write the fields into a file named after the line number. Output one line per field.
2. Repeat step 1 until the input CSV file is exhausted.
3. Use [paste](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/paste-invocation.html) to merge all output files into a big one.

Comment: Shouldn't `cat` be used instead of `paste` for transposing?

Comment: That depends on whether one chooses the source file's ordinate or abscissa as major axis. I tested that my solution is easier to program and it is guaranteed to require only one pass over the input.