# How do I read a CSV file column by column in order to transpose it?

Tags: perl, csv, large-files, transpose

I have a data set in the following format:

```
snp,T2DG0200001,T2DG0200002,T2DG0200003,T2DG0200004
3_60162,AA,AA,AA,AA
3_61495,AA,AA,GA,GA
3_61466,GG,GG,CG,CG
```

The real data is much larger than this, extending to millions of rows and about a thousand columns. My eventual goal is to transpose this monstrosity and output the result in a text file (or CSV file or whatever, doesn't matter).

I need to feed the data to my computer piece by piece so as not to overload my memory. I read the CSV file line by line, and then transpose it, and write to file. I then loop back and repeat the steps, appending to the text file as I go.

The problem of course is that I am supposed to append the text file **column by column** instead of by row if the result is the transpose of the original data file. But a friend told me that is not feasible in Perl code. I am wondering if I can read the data column by column. Is there something similar such as the [`getline` method](http://p3rl.org/IO%3a%3aHandle#io-getline) which I used in my original code

```
while (my $row = $csv->getline ($fh)) {
```

that can return columns instead of rows? Something akin to a Unix `cut` command would be preferred, if it does not require loading the entire data into memory.

Comment: -1 for substantially reposting http://stackoverflow.com/q/11832625 without explaining why the answers you received were not suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a CSV is simply a text file; it consists of one big long line of text characters, so there is no random access to columns.  Ideally, you would put the CSV into a database, which will then be able to do this directly.

However, barring that, I believe you *could* do this in Perl with a little cleverness.  My approach would be something like this:

```
my @filehandles;
my $line = 0;    

while (my $row = $csv->getline ($fh)<FILE>)
{
   #open an output file for each column!
   if (not defined $filehandles[0])
   {
       for (0..$#$row)
       {
           local $handle;
           open $handle, ">column_$_.txt" or die "Oops!";
           push @filehandles, $handle;
       }
   }

   #print each column to its respective output file.
   for (0..$#$row)
   {
       print $filehandles[$_] $row->[$_] . ",";
   }

   #This is going to take a LONG time, so show some sign of life.
   print '.' if (($line++ % 1000) == 0);
}
```

At the end, each column would be printed as a row in its own text file.  Don't forget to close all the files, then open them all again for reading, then write them into a single output file one at a time.  My guess is this would be slow, but fast enough to do millions of rows, as long as you don't have to do it very often.  And it wouldn't face memory limitations.

Comment: Upon reflection, this probably isn't the greatest approach if you have thousands of columns.  You may run into limitations on the number of open files.

Comment: If this results in too many open filehandles, you could modify it to work in chunks.  Say, write the first 500 columns to text files, then the next 500, and so on until it is done.  In that way, you would only have to read through the input file a few times rather than thousands.

Comment: One last thing: for a less kludgy solution, there are many Perl modules that implement a simple database. One example: http://search.cpan.org/~pmqs/DB_File-1.826/DB_File.pm

Comment: http://p3rl.org/FileCache is the usual work-around for the problem of too many open handles, requires very little change in code compared with a database module.

Answer (score 0):

If the file does not fit in your computers memory, your program has to read through it multiple times. There is no way around it.

There might be modules that obscure or hide this fact - like DBD::CSV - but those just do the same work behind the scenes.

Comment: -1 Of course there is a way around it: [process the input line by line](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11832725), not column by column; then only one pass is needed. The end result is the same.

Comment: As a general rule, answers of "you can't do that in Perl" are doomed to be disproved.